# Javascript clear all input when changing dropdown value

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, vue.js

how would one go about clearing other textboxes when changing the value of a dropdown with JavaScript? When I change the value in a specific dropdown I want the other text fields that have filled in to clear. I am using Vue.js and Laravel.

Here is my dropdown:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
    <label for="value" class="control-label">Instruments</label>
    <div>
        <select name="instruments" class="form-control select sel-primary" v-model="instruction.instrument" v-on:change="autofillResult(instruction.putType)" >
            <option v-for="instrument in instruments" v-bind:value="instrument">
                @{{ instrument.name }}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The fields I want to clear when I change the dropdown value:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-1">
    <label for="strike" class="control-label">Strike</label>
    <input name="strike" type="number" v-model="instruction.strike" class="form-control"  :disabled="instruction.putType == 'Future'">
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-1">
    <label for="" class="control-label">Buy/Sell</label>
    <div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button name="buySellButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">@{{instruction.type}} <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li v-for="(val, key) in types"><a @click="selectBuyItem(val)">@{{ key }}</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-1">
    <label for="Quantity" class="control-label">Quantity</label>
    <div>
        <input name="quantity" type="text" v-model="instruction.quantity" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-md-1">
    <label for="" class="control-label">Price</label>
    <div>
        <input name="price" type="text" v-model="instruction.price" class="form-control">
    </div>
</div>
```

My Vue Code under methods:

```
autofillResult: function(item){
    var price = _.chain(this.latestprice).where({'InstrumentName':this.instruction.instrument.name, 'ContractDate': this.instruction.contract.contractDate}).pluck('Last').first().value();

    if(this.instruction.contract.strikeInterval != undefined){
        var str  =  this.instruction.contract.strikeInterval;
        this.instruction.strike = (Math.round(price / str))*str;
        this.instruction.price = price;
        this.instruction.quantity = 1;
    }
},
```

Comment: Do you want to clear text fields ?

Comment: You already have an `onchange` listener on the select, there itself you can set the `v-model` of the other inputs to an empty string ....for example : `this.instruction..price = ''`

Comment: Im not sure how to structure the if statement that when the dropdown changes then the values must clear

Comment: @CasperSL yes I want to clear the textboxes

Answer (score 0):

The clearing code goes in your autofillResults method, called when the select changes. **You clear the input by clearing the variable that stores it's value.** Don't try to do anything directly on the input. The input should be the dumb reflection of it's variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can empty text fields inside `autofillResult()` like below,

```
autofillResult: function(item){
  //add all text fields here
  this.instruction.price = "";
}
```